# A vector sequence multiplied by a sequence of scalars converges to the products of the limits of both sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, vector-spaces

I need to prove the following statement:

> If $\{\vec{x}_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ converges to the vector $\vec{x}$ and $\{a_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ to a real number $a$ then the sequences of vectors, $\{a_n\vec{x}_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, converges to $a\vec{x}$.

Work so far: 
Let $\varepsilon > 0$.It remains to prove that there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for every natural number $n > N$, we have
$$
\|a_n\vec{x}_n-a\vec{x}\|< \varepsilon.
$$
By the definition of the limit, there is a integer $N_1>0$ such that, when $n > N_1$, we have
$$
\|\vec{x}_n-\vec{x}\|< \sqrt{\varepsilon}.
$$
Similarly, by the definition of the limit, there is a integer $N_2>0$ such that, when $n > N_2$, we have
$$
|a_n-a|< \sqrt{\varepsilon}.
$$
We choose $N = \max(N_1, N_2)$. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$. As the inequalities hold we can multiply them to obtain
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon=\sqrt{\varepsilon} \sqrt{\varepsilon}&> |a_n-a|\|\vec{x}_n-\vec{x}\| \\
&=\||a_n-a|\vec{x}_n-|a_n-a|\vec{x}\|
\end{align*}
From there I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go that route, then do
\begin{align}\| a_n x_n - ax\| &\le \|a_n x_n - a x_n\| + \|a x_n - a x\| \\
&\le |a_n-a| \|x_n\| + |a| \|x_n-x\|\\
&\le |a_n-a| (\|x_n-x\|+\|x\|) + |a|\|x_n-x\|
\end{align}
and note $\|a_n-a\| \to 0$ and $\|x_n-x\| \to 0$.

---

Alternatively, note that if the vector is finite-dimensional, the notion of convergence here is equivalent to pointwise convergence. By checking convergence in each component, we easily have $a_n x_{n,i} \to a x_i$ for each component $i$ by the usual one-dimensional limit properties.

Comment: Is there a way I could use the epsilon definition of the limit to prove the statement?

Comment: @AzJ Yes, just note $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ and $\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon$ for large $n$, and then the last line is upper bounded by $\epsilon(\epsilon+\|x\|)+|a|\epsilon < \epsilon'$ if $\epsilon<\min(1,\epsilon'/(1+\|x\|+|a|))$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: convergent sequences are bounded.

Edit: I would also rewrite your inequalities this way:

$$
\|a_nx_n -ax\|\leq \|a_nx-ax\| + \|ax_n-ax\|
$$